# Continuity of a function $f:[0,T]^2\to\Bbb R$ which vanishes on diagonal

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let us consider a function $f:[0,M]\times[0,M]\to\Bbb R$ which vanishes on the diagonal (i.e. $f(x,x)=0\;\;\;\forall\;0\le x\le T$).
Let us suppose there exists $\lambda>0$ such that
$$
\|f\|_{\lambda}:=\sup_{x,y\in[0,T]\\x\neq y}\frac{|f(x,y)|}{|x-y|^{\lambda}}<+\infty.
$$
How can I prove $f$ is continuous on the whole $[0,M]^2$?

**EDIT:** $f$ is not an arbitrary function. The structure is the following.

Let us consider $h:[0,T]^3\to\Bbb R$ a continuous function such that $h(s,u,t)=0$ whenever $s=u$ or $u=t$.

Fix then $\gamma,\mu>0$ and define, for such a $h$
$$
\|h\|_{\gamma,\rho}:=\sup_{s,t,u\in[0,T],t\neq u\neq s}\frac{|h(s,u,t)|}{|t-u|^{\rho}|u-s|^{\gamma}}
$$
from which we define
$$
\|h\|_{\lambda}:=\inf\left\{\sum_j\|h^{(j)}\|_{\rho_j,\lambda-\rho_j}\;:\;h=\sum_jh^{(j)},\;0<\rho_j<\lambda\right\}\;,
$$
where this last infimum is taken over all sequences $\{h^{(j)}\}_j$ of $3$-variables functions $(s,t,u)\mapsto h^j(s,t,u)$, which vanishes whenever $s=u$ or $u=t$, such that $h=\sum_jh^{(j)}$ and all choices of the numbers $0<\rho_j<\lambda$.

Now, $\|\cdot\|_{\lambda}$ is a norm on the set of these functions.

Let us fix an $h$ such that $\|h\|_{\lambda}<+\infty$.

Take a $B:[0,T]^2\to\Bbb R$ continous, such that vanishes on the diagonal and
$$
h(s,u,t)=-B(u,t)+B(s,t)-B(s,u)
$$
(accept such a $B$ exists).

At this point we fix $(x,y)\in[0,T]^2$, we take wlog $0\le x<y\le T$ and consider the dyadic partition of the interval
$$
r_i^n:=x+\frac{y-x}{2^n}i\;,\;\;0\le i\le 2^n.
$$

So we can now define $f_n$ as follows:
$$
f_n(y,x):=B(y,x)-\sum_{i=0}^{2^n-1}B(r_{i+1}^n,r_i^n)\;.
$$
It can be shown that $\{f_n(y,x)\}_{n\ge1}$ converges to a finite number $f(y,x)$; repeating the argument for any pair $(x,y)\in[0,T]^2$ we define a function which vanishes on the diagonal and which respects the first estimate I wrote.

How can I show this $f$ is continuous?

Comment: The result is not true. Take $f(x, y) = \chi_{|x-y|>0.5}$. There must be some missing hypothesis.

Comment: @Gribouillis: $f$ has others hypothesis, but using them it seems (to me) all is getting complicated. However I'm going to edit.

Comment: It is indeed getting complicated. It seems to me that continuity is an improvement over the existence of $f$, that is to say the convergence of the $f_n$. So I suggest that you start from the detailed proof of convergence.

Comment: @Gribouillis: done. However thanks. If you have the patience to take a look at it, tell me if you notice any mistake! Thanks!

Comment: I would like to know the reasons for the downvote.

Making the identity of downvoters public should be something not to underrate

Answer (score 1):

Let us see that $M$ is continous in a fixed point $(t_0,s_0)$.\
Let us fix $\varepsilon>0$ and search for some $\delta>0$
such that
$$
\left|M_{ts}-M_{t_0s_0}\right|<\varepsilon\;\;\;\forall (t,s)\in\operatorname B_{(t_0,s_0)}(\delta)
$$
where $\operatorname B_{(x_0,y_0)}(r)$ is the open ball centered in $(x_0,y_0)$ and radius $r>0$.

Denote the $n$-th dyadic partition of $[s,t]$ already used in Step 2 with $\Pi_{n}^{[s,t]}$, specifying now the interval $[s,t]$.

So, calling $S^{\Pi_n^{[s,t]}}:=\sum_{i=0}^{2^n-1}B_{r_{i+1}^nr_i^n}$, where clearly $r_i^n=s+\frac{t-s}{2^n}i$, let us rewrite the above equation with this notation:
$$
M_{ts}^{\Pi_n^{[s,t]}}=B_{ts}-S^{\Pi_n^{[s,t]}}.
$$
Moreover we have seen $\left\{M_{ts}^{\Pi_n^{[s,t]}}\right\}_{n\ge1}$ admits limit $M_{ts}$, so does $\left\{S^{\Pi_n^{[s,t]}}\right\}_{n\ge1}$; we denote this last limit $S_{ts}$.

We will consider different cases according on all the possible relations between the two intervals $[s,t]$ and $[s_0,t_0]$, supposing always, without loss of generality, that $[s,t]\cap[s_0,t_0]\neq\emptyset$ and $[s,t]\neq[s_0,t_0]$.

\begin{equation}\label{cond}%cond
{Case A:}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; [s,t]\setminus[s_0,t_0]\neq\emptyset\neq[s_0,t_0]\setminus[s,t].
\end{equation}
We now split $S$ in a suitable way, so we can write
\begin{equation}\label{candice}%candice
M_{ts}^{\Pi_n^{[s,t]}}
=B_{ts}+
\left(B_{b_na_n}
-S^{\Pi_n^{[s,t]}\cap[s_0,t_0]}\right)-B_{b_na_n}
-S^{\Pi_n^{[s,t]}\setminus[s_0,t_0]}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}\label{merda}%merda
M_{t_0s_0}^{\Pi_n^{[s_0,t_0]}}
=B_{t_0s_0}+
\left(B_{d_nc_n}
-S^{\Pi_n^{[s_0,t_0]}\cap[s,t]}
\right)-B_{d_nc_n}
-S^{\Pi_n^{[s_0,t_0]}\setminus[s,t]}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{align*}
a_n&:=\min\left\{\Pi_n^{[s,t]}\cap[s_0,t_0]\right\},\;\;\;b_n:=\max\left\{\Pi_n^{[s,t]}\cap[s_0,t_0]\right\}\\
c_n&:=\min\left\{\Pi_n^{[s_0,t_0]}\cap[s,t]\right\},\;\;\;d_n:=\max\left\{\Pi_n^{[s_0,t_0]}\cap[s,t]\right\}\;.
\end{align*}
Now, as $n\to+\infty$, supposing without loss of generality that the intersections are not empty, it is clear that,
$$
a_n\to \inf\left\{\bigcup_{n\ge1}\Pi_n^{[s,t]}\cap[s_0,t_0]\right\}=\min\left\{[s,t]\cap[s_0,t_0]\right\}=:p
$$
where the last equality follows since $\bigcup_{n\ge1}\Pi_n^{[s,t]}$ is dense in $[s,t]$.

Similarly we have that  $b_n\to \max\left\{[s,t]\cap[s_0,t_0]\right\}=:q$ and $c_n\to p\;$, $d_n\to q$.

Hence it should be clear that
$$
B_{b_na_n}-S^{\Pi_n^{[s,t]}\cap[s_0,t_0]}\longrightarrow M_{qp}\;,\;\;n\to+\infty
$$
and 
$$
B_{d_nc_n}-S^{\Pi_n^{[s_0,t_0]}\cap[s,t]}\longrightarrow M_{qp}\;,\;\;n\to+\infty.
$$
Moreover, setting
$$
\xi:=\inf\left\{\bigcup_{n\ge1}\Pi_n^{[s,t]}\setminus[s_0,t_0]\right\}=\inf\left\{[s,t]\setminus[s_0,t_0]\right\},\;\;\;
\eta:=\sup \left\{[s,t]\setminus[s_0,t_0]\right\}
$$
and 
$$
\xi^*:=\inf\left\{[s_0,t_0]\setminus[s,t]\right\},\;\;\;\eta^*:=\sup \left\{[s_0,t_0]\setminus[s,t]\right\}
$$
and passing to the limit in the above equations for $n\to+\infty$, they turn into
$$
M_{ts}=B_{ts}+M_{qp}-B_{qp}-S_{\eta\xi}
$$
and
$$
M_{t_0s_0}=B_{t_0s_0}+M_{qp}-B_{qp}-S_{\eta^*\xi^*}
$$
respectively, from which we immediately have
$$
\left|M_{ts}-M_{t_0s_0}\right|
\le\left|B_{ts}-B_{t_0s_0}\right|+\left|S_{\eta\xi}\right|+\left|S_{\eta^*\xi^*}\right|\;.
$$

Recalling then that $B$ is continous, we find $\delta_1>0$ such that $\left|B_{ts}-B_{t_0s_0}\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}3$ for every $(t,s)\in\operatorname B_{(t_0,s_0)}(\delta_1)$.

Next, since $\|M\|_{\lambda}<+\infty$ (Step 2), we have that $|M_{ts}|\le\|M\|_{\lambda}|t-s|^{\lambda}\;\;\;\forall s,t\in[0,T]$, from which $M$ is continuous  on the diagonal of $[0,T]^2$. Now, since $S_{ts}=B_{ts}-M_{ts}$ and $B$ is continuous on the whole $[0,T]^2$, it follows that  $S$ is continuous on the diagonal too.

Now, observing the pair $(s,t)$ respects the restriction of Case A if and only if it belongs to
$$
X_{(s_0,t_0)}:=\left\{(s,t)\in[0,T]^2:(0\le s<s_0<t< t_0\le T)\vee(0\le s_0<s<t_0<t\le T)\right\},
$$
we have that
$$
\lim_{\substack{(s,t)\to(s_0,t_0)\\(s,t)\in X_{(s_0,t_0)}}}|\eta-\xi|=0
$$
and thus
$$
\lim_{\substack{(s,t)\to(s_0,t_0)\\(s,t)\in X_{(s_0,t_0)}}}S_{\eta\xi}=0\;.
$$
Hence we can find $\delta_2>0$ such that $\left|S_{\eta\xi}\right|, \left|S_{\eta^*\xi^*}\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}3$ for every $(t,s)\in\operatorname B_{(t_0,s_0)}(\delta_2)\cap X_{(s_0,t_0)}$ and thus, putting all togheter and setting $\delta_A:=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$, we finally get 
$$
|M_{ts}-M_{t_0s_0}|<\varepsilon\;\;\;\forall(t,s)\in\operatorname B_{(t_0,s_0)}(\delta_A)\cap X_{(s_0,t_0)}.
$$
\newline
\begin{equation}\label{cond2}%cond2
Case B:\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; [s,t]\setminus[s_0,t_0]=\emptyset.
\end{equation}
Now a pair $(s,t)$ satisfy this condition if and only if it belongs to
$$
Y_{(s_0,t_0)}:=\left\{(s,t)\in[0,T]^2:0\le s_0\le s<t\le t_0\le T\right\}.
$$
In particular in this case we have $[s_0,t_0]\setminus[s,t]=[s_0,s[\,\cup\,]t,t_0]$; as did before we split $S$ conveniently (but now the equation for $M_{ts}^{\Pi_n^{[s_0,t_0]}}$ is enough):
$$
%\begin{equation}\label{louise}%louise
M_{t_0s_0}^{\Pi_n^{[s_0,t_0]}}
=B_{t_0s_0}+
\left(B_{ts}
-S^{\Pi_n^{[s_0,t_0]}\cap[s,t]}
\right)-B_{ts}
-S^{\Pi_n^{[s_0,t_0]}\cap[s_0,s[}-S^{\Pi_n^{[s_0,t_0]}\cap]t,t_0]}
%\end{equation}
$$
and letting $n\to+\infty$ this last equation turns into
$$
M_{t_0s_0}=B_{t_0s_0}+M_{ts}-B_{ts}-S_{ss_0}-S_{t_0t};,
$$
from which we immediately get
$$
\left|M_{ts}-M_{t_0s_0}\right|
\le\left|B_{ts}-B_{t_0s_0}\right|+\left|S_{ss_0}\right|+\left|S_{t_0t}\right|\;.
$$
and with the same arguments used in Case A, we find a $\delta_B>0$ such that 
$$
|M_{ts}-M_{t_0s_0}|<\varepsilon\;\;\;\forall(t,s)\in\operatorname B_{(t_0,s_0)}(\delta_B)\cap Y_{(s_0,t_0)}.
$$

\begin{equation}\label{cond3}%cond3
Case C:\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; [s_0,t_0]\setminus[s,t]=\emptyset.
\end{equation}
Now a pair $(s,t)$ satisfy this condition if and only if it belongs to
$$
Z_{(s_0,t_0)}:=\left\{(s,t)\in[0,T]^2:0\le s\le s_0<t_0\le t\le T\right\}.
$$
It is identical to Case B; thus there exists $\delta_C>0$ such that
$$
|M_{ts}-M_{t_0s_0}|<\varepsilon\;\;\;\forall(t,s)\in\operatorname B_{(t_0,s_0)}(\delta_C)\cap Z_{(s_0,t_0)}.
$$

Since $X_{(s_0,t_0)}\cup Y_{(s_0,t_0)}\cup Z_{(s_0,t_0)}=[0,T]^2\setminus\{(s_0,t_0)\}$, setting $\delta:=\min\{\delta_A, \delta_B, \delta_C\}$, we can finally conclude that
$$
|M_{ts}-M_{t_0s_0}|<\varepsilon\;\;\;\forall(t,s)\in\operatorname B_{(t_0,s_0)}(\delta),
$$
obtaining then the continuity of $M$ at the point $(s_0,t_0)$.

Comment: Frankly speaking, it is so technical and there is so much context I'm not aware of that I don't think I can reasonably evaluate the correctness of your proof. Good luck with this, some results need that much complexity.

Comment: No problem! And thanks again! :-)